# Topic Clarity - Asking for the name of an opening?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Often while playing I'm forced to make certain moves in an opening in order to defend against certain obvious attacks. I would like to ask a question to identify an opening that either my opponent is playing, or I'm defending/attacking against. Sometimes plugging the moves into google yields the results, sometimes it doesn't. For example:

> Can anyone tell me the name of the opening white used in this game?

```
[fen ""]
1.e4 c5 2.Nf3 Nc6 3.d4 b6 4.Nc3 Bb7 5.d5 Nd4 6.Nxd4 cxd4 7.Qxd4 f6 8.Be2 e5 9.dxe6 dxe6  10.Qxd8+ Rxd8 11.O-O Bd6 12.Be3
```

Would a question of this type be on topic? It has a definitive answer, even if that answer is 'White started with [chess opening], but transposed into something else' or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is almost certainly on topic.  For example, see a [similar question asking about the Scotch Game](https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/218/12).

The only reason this might be off topic would be if it were something silly like `1. f3 e5 2. g3 d5` etc.

Comment: `1. f3 e5 2. g3 d5` is known as "Gedult's Opening" on lichess.org (1 master game) and "Barnes' Opening" on chess.com (3 master games), though it is clearly a dubious opening at best.